# Get user list from Taleo Connect Client

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

We're using the Recruiting Taleo (14A) module and I was wanting to pull a list of external and internal users (login, email, internal/external, etc) from Taleo Connect Client (12A).

Does anyone know how to do this? Or where to pull the data from? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the entity you are looking for is `Candidate`. Taleo Connect Client has a built in template for exporting candidates, which includes usernames and email addresses.

1. Open Taleo Connect Client and select **File → New → New Export Wizard**.
2. Click the **Product** dropdown and select your Taleo product version.
3. In the list of entities, select **Candidate**.
4. Under the **Template** section, select **Create export from a template**.
5. Click the **Template** dropdown and select **Standard Candidate export (CSV-ENTITY)**.
6. Click **Finish** to create your new export.

<sub>**Note**: The candidate export template for Recruiting Taleo 14A appears to be based on Recruiting 10.0.1. This can be fixed either by creating an export without a template, or by changing `productCode="PRO1001"` to `productCode="RC1401"` in the source file.</sub>

[image: Template for exporting candidates]

You can customize your export's projections and filters to suit your needs. Alternatively, if you don't want to start from a template, you can create a new export instead.

Once your export is saved, you can run it by creating a new configuration.

1. Open **File → New → New Configuration Wizard**.
2. Select **Based on an export specification**.
3. Click the three dots **...** next to **File** and select your export.
4. Click **Next** to move to the next page.
5. Select your Taleo **Endpoint**, then click **Finish**.
6. Save & run your configuration.